# Batch files - names

Tags: string, batch-file, move

I have a code that looks for png files with a specific pattern on the desktop and moves them to another directory.
While going over the files, I want to check if there is the pattern in the name.
This is how I did it:

```
for %%f in (C:\Users\user\Desktop\*.png) do (
    if %%f==Hearthstone Screenshot*.png (
    move %%f C:\destination\
    )   
)
```

Note: All the needed files start with Hearthstone Screenshot then some numbers.
My main problem is in line 2. I can't make it work.

Comment: What's wrong here?

Comment: @double-beep OP says, must start with `Hearthstone Screenshot` and he does not know how, so I do not understand your question?

Comment: When I have problems like this one, I try adding something like `echo %%f` as a command before the `if...`

Comment: `if` doesn't support wildcards. What's wrong with `move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Hearthstone Screenshot*.png" "C:\destination\"`?

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon you needs, perhaps this is what you're looking for…

```bat
@RoboCopy "%UserProfile%\Desktop" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\HearthStone_Screenshots" "HearthStone Screenshot*.png" /MOV>Nul 2>&1
```

This should automatically create the holding directory, `HearthStone_Screenshots` if it doesn't already exist.

---

*Note:*
I have corrected what I'm assuming to be your very poor spelling issues. If those files and directories should be named using `ea` instead of `ee` please re-adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this:

```
move C:\Users\user\Desktop\HearthstoneScreanshot*.png C:\Users\user\Desktop\Hearthstonescreanshot\
```

Comment: Missing space between `Hearthstone Screenshot` and double quotes also missing.

Comment: also `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Hearth...` might make sense.

Comment: And `2>nul` also.